# How can I access the controller instance associated with a directive from the link function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I access the controller instance associated with a directive from the link function?

```
return {
            template: template,
            controller: controller,
            controllerAs: 'myCtrl', // How do I access the controller instance from the link function?
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {}
};
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: I think by passing ``ctrls`` as 4th parameter to link function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link function in directive accepts 4th parameter. You can do the following:

```
         return {
            template: template,
            controller: controller,
            controllerAs: 'myCtrl', 
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {}
         };
```